# Return 0 or 1 rows from function

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible for a function to return one record, but return zero records if there is an empty result set. For example:

If I have an empty table that contains no data...

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
    FooID SERIAL CONSTRAINT PK_Foo PRIMARY KEY,
    FooValue INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

... and a function ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_OneFoo()
RETURNS Foo
AS $$
    SELECT
        FooID,
        FooValue
    FROM
        Foo
    LIMIT 1
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

... then ...

```
SELECT GET_OneFoo()
```

... results in ...

```
Total query runtime: 11 ms.
1 row retrieved.
```

... however ...

```
SELECT
    FooID,
    FooValue
FROM
    Foo
LIMIT 1
```

... results in ...

```
Total query runtime: 10 ms.
0 rows retrieved.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RETURNS setof Foo
```

in instead of

```
RETURNS Foo
```

The later returns a composite type:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#AEN51678

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought this might be the case. Does this have any effect on performance?

Comment: It does affect the contexts you can invoke the function in a little bit, and it changes the semantics when the function is invoked in the `SELECT` list - returning zero rows is different to returning a `NULL` row. It shouldn't make any significant difference to performance, though.